# How to reuse prometheus gauge metric?

Tags: prometheus

I am very new to python and prometheus. Any help will be appreciated.
I am using prometheus client. I created a gauge instance in file A

```
    self.spark_time = prom.Gauge(
        "SparkJobTime", 
        "Gauge pod running time", 
        self.metric_labels
    )
```

And I am setting metrics in file A as well

```
self.spark_time.labels(job=job_name).set(pod_duration.total_seconds())
```

In file b, I also want to use this `SparkJobTime` metric.
I tried in file b

```
self.spark_time = prom.Gauge(
    "SparkJobTime", 
    "Gauge pod running time", 
    self.metric_labels
)
```

then it companies about Duplicated timeseries in CollectorRegistry...
How should I used this SparkJobTime metric in file b?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is unclear... What is `self` in `self spark_time`? Usually `self` in Python refers to the instance variables in the definition of a class. Is that where you're defining the Gauge?

When you duplicate that line `self.spark_time = prom.Gauge(...)`, you create a new Gauge with the same name and other details and this is not permitted.

Once you create the Gauge and assign it `foo = prom.Gauge(...)`, you should only need to ever refer to it as `foo` and not duplicate creating it.

In file b, if `self.spark_time` represents the same "thing", you should just be able to:

```py
self.spark_time.labels(job=job_name).set(pod_duration.total_seconds())
```

I suspect one problem may be that you're assigning the Gauge to an instance variable (`spark_time`) of some class. Once you've done that in one of the class' functions, you don't need to do it again.